# Google Maps API V3 - ignore previous info

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code that work well but there's only one problem. I have a list of vehicles and I want it to center the map to the position of the vehicle that I clicked. The problem is when I click more than 2 vehicles, the variance keep the previous vehicle's info and center the map to any of 2 or more vehicles that I clicked. What I wanted is to show only for the latest click and ignore all previous click. I tried few ways but failed. How can I fix it? Thanks.

```
    //Creation de Map
// ------------------
// Enable the visual refresh
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
// Variables globales
var map = null;
var Table_Pins = {};     // Liste des Pins affichées
var Pos_Info = null;     // Dit sur quel marker se situe l'infobulle
var Liste_Points = []; // Pour la mémorisation du tracé
var route = null;
var markers = [];
var _this = this;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
function initialize() 
    {
      var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.665, 7.052),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, //Type de carte
                mapTypeControl: true,
                panControl: true,
                zoomControl: true, //Zoom
                scaleControl: true, //Echelle
                scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM},
                streetViewControl: true
                } ;
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);   
    }
//------------------------
// Ouverture du WebBrowser
// -----------------------
try { google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);}
catch (ex){ alert("vous devez etre connecte a l'internet...");}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//*************************************************************************************
//                          Affichage des véhicules
//*************************************************************************************
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var infowindows=[];
var title_markers=[];
var openedInfoWindow = null;
var infowindow;
var title_marker;
var TraceBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var MarkerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
function Affiche_Pin(Lat, Long, immat, type, site, vitesse, date)
    { var myPin = Table_Pins[immat];
        if (typeof myPin != "undefined") 
         {
           myPin.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long));
           myPin.html = '<b style="color:green">Véhicule : ' + immat + ' ' + '</b><br>' +
            'Site : ' + site + '<br>' +
            'Type : ' + type + '<br>' +
            'Vitesse : ' + vitesse + ' km/h' + '<br>' +
            'Date : ' + date + '<br>';
           if (Pos_Info == myPin) 
             { infowindow.setContent(myPin.html); 
              infowindow.open(map, marker); } 
         }
// -------------------------------
// Création de la Pin et placement
// -------------------------------
else{
    var imageMarqueur = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon15.png',
          new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
          new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
    var ombreMarqueur = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon15s.png',
          new google.maps.Size(56, 32),
          new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          new google.maps.Point(16, 32));

    var vehlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long) ;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: vehlatlng,
         icon: imageMarqueur,
         shadow: ombreMarqueur           });
    marker.html = '<b style="color:green">Véhicule : ' + immat + ' ' + '</b><br>' +
            'Site : ' + site + '<br>' +
            'Type : ' + type + '<br>' +
            'Vitesse : ' + vitesse + ' km/h' + '<br>' +
            'Date : ' + date + '<br>';
    marker.tooltip_html = '<b style="color:green">Véhicule : ' + immat + ' ' + '</b>';

     infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: marker.html,    
     position: vehlatlng });

     title_marker = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: marker.tooltip_html,    
     position: vehlatlng });

     markers.push(marker);
    MarkerBounds.extend(marker.position);
     infowindows.push(infowindow);
     title_markers.push(title_marker);
     marker.setMap(map);

// Evenement "Click" et "infowindowopen" du marker
// ---------------------------
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  if (openedInfoWindow != null) openedInfoWindow.close();  // <-- changed this
  infowindow.setContent(marker.html); 
  infowindow.open(map, marker); 
  Pos_Info = marker;
  // added next 4 lines
  openedInfoWindow = infowindow;
  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
      openedInfoWindow = null;
  });
});
// Marker show tooltip 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        title_marker.setContent(marker.tooltip_html); 
        title_marker.open(map, marker); 
  });
  // Marker hide tooltip 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
        title_marker.close(); 
        });
         Table_Pins[immat] = marker;
      }//end else
   }//end function affiche_pin  

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//**************************************************************************************
//                          On centre le véhicule
//**************************************************************************************
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var myPin;
function Centrer_Pin(immat) {
     myPin = Table_Pins[immat];
    if (typeof myPin != "undefined") 
            { //var myPins = myPin;
              infowindow.close();
               map.setZoom(13);
               map.setCenter(myPin.getPosition());
               infowindow.setContent(myPin.html); 
               infowindow.open(map, myPin);
     //Position changed ---------------------
       google.maps.event.addListener(myPin, 'position_changed', function() {
       map.panTo(myPin.getPosition());
          if (openedInfoWindow != null) openedInfoWindow.close();  // <-- changed this
          infowindow.setContent(myPin.html); 
          infowindow.open(map, myPin); 
          openedInfoWindow = infowindow;
             google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
             openedInfoWindow = null;
             });
             alert("bomb bomb");
         });
      //Zoom changed -------------------------
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        infowindow.close();});  
    }  

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: ok, the link to the js [http://jsfiddle.net/SdxsT/]

Comment: error 404 no such page. EDIT No it's ok. You just added the bracket to your link.

Comment: sorry bout that, but i'm not sure why... ok,here [http://jsfiddle.net/SdxsT/1/

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not a working example. The purpose of providing a jsfiddle is a way for as to run it and see live the problem.

Comment: but the position is receive from the server as it update live, actually my problem is more to javascript, isn't?

Comment: That's what I think. You can hardcode some positions. I'm not doing this to be an ass, but in general that's the way stackoverflow works. You have to help the people trying to solve your problem.

Comment: Try printing the position of the marker that the map tries to center to.

Comment: im so sorry about that, ok, i included a link to the photo i uploaded, [http://xuperhost.com/map/map.png 
as you'll see from the picture, the blue wording mean the vehicle is on the road, so when i click any of the vehile, it will always show the marker at the position of the marker. which mean, it need to ignore any vehicle that i clicked previously. But in my case, the map jump from marker to marker of vehicle that I clicked before when new position available.

Comment: It must be something with the way you add your listeners. Do you perhaps call the function Centrer_Pin for the same immat more than once?

Comment: yes, each time i click on a vehicule, the map set the marker position as center of the map and the function Centrer_Pin is called. Actually that's what i'm trying to fix, when i called the function more than once, it keep all the position of the vehicule I clicked before. What i want is only keep the latest position.

Comment: ok, i solved the problem, i just need to define the "myPin" variable as global. Thanks for the hint. :)

Comment: It's still wrong although it works. Check my answer. If you want to test what I'm saying, just add an alert inside the listener I am talking about. It will be fired as many times as you have clicked the marker, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Centrer_Pin is called every time you click on a marker you have to remove the following listener from there

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myPin, 'position_changed', function() {..
```

and put it somewhere else, where you call it only once for every marker you have. It should be with the creation of your `Table_Pins[immat]`

What you are doing now, is adding multiple listeners for the same marker, that's why you have that bouncing you mentioned. Every listener you added is being called. That's why it works for the first click, and after that it all goes wrong.

Comment: it works, i just need to define the "myPin" variable as global. Thanks for the hint. :). but i still need the listener to always make sure the marker is at the center of the map.

Comment: The listener is not just a function, it's a function fired when an event happens. If you leave it as it is, it will bind so many times that it will cause a crash. Anyway do what you want, it's your program.

Comment: A listener is bind only once, and it's being called every time the specified event fires.

Comment: yes, you are totaly right, in that case, where should I put the function for the listener ? in initialize() where I defined my map? I updated my code above.

Comment: Yes in initialize it would be a good place. You have to make sure that when you do that you have initialized all the components you need. The array with your markers is initialized and, infowindow is created. If this solves your problem please mark answer as accepted